# VBA Excel: How to select only numeric values in a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I used Range.Find to locate a string called "Qty", now I want to select all the numbers in that column.

I would use .End(xlDown) to get the last row, however the last used cell in that column is not a number but text, and I don't want it in my selection.

So I would like to know how to select the range consisting only of quatities, so I can then copy it into another workbook.

Thank you.

Comment: IsNumeric: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463236/loop-through-each-row-of-a-range-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you found the word "qty" and wanted to select the numbers between that cell and the bottom cell. Use the offset attribute -

```
Sub test()
Dim qty As Range
Dim qtylast As Range
Set qty = Range("A1:H1").Find("qty")
Set qtylast = qty.End(xlDown)

Range(qty.Offset(1), qtylast.Offset(-1)).Select

End Sub
```